# Client no show in WSUS console (windows server 2016)

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, windows-update, windows-server-2016, wsus

I am trying to configure client (windows7) for contact with  WSUS server(windows server 2016) by config registry (none AD) as below :

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]
"ElevateNonAdmins"=dword:00000001
"TargetGroup"="North_30"
"TargetGroupEnabled"=dword:00000001
"WUServer"="http://192.168.99.7:8530"
"WUStatusServer"="http://192.168.99.7:8530"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU]
"NoAutoUpdate"=dword:00000000
"AUOptions"=dword:00000002
"UseWUServer"=dword:00000001
```

---

And config gpedit.msc  Configure Automatic Updates -> select Enable.

First time client appear in WSUS server console but the next day not see.
after that  we press check for update in client then appear in WSUS server

**How to fix client for always show in WSUS console without  press check for update in client**